# Liferay only show page that have children

Tags: java, permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I'm working with permissions on Liferay and i'm facing a problem. I have this page structure:

```
->Page 1
---->Child page 1
---->Child page 2
---->Child page 3
->Page 2
(...)
```

Each child page (1,2,3) have diferent permissions. What i want is to make 'Page 1' only visible to users who have at least access to one child page. For other hand the page should not be visible if the users don't have access to any child pages.

I've already removed all the permissions to 'Page 1' expecting that it assumes the children permissions but with this the page is always invisible.

What can i do to solve this?

**IMPERFECT SOLUTION **

Well, in the Page 1 permissions i set to 'visible to all logged users' and gave the desired permissions to the child pages, and then im the navigation.vm i changed this way:

```
<ul id="mainTopMenu">
    ## First Level Generation
    #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)

            #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())

                <li>
                    <a> $nav_item.getName()</a>
                    <ul>
                        ## Second Level Generation
                        #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                            <li>            
                                <a href="$nav_child.getURL()">
                                    $nav_child.getName()
                                </a>
                            </li>   
                        #end

                    </ul>
                </li>
    #end
</ul>
```

What this code does is always to show the pages that have children. But this will only work if i only have pages with children, but that's not the case. I have 3 pages that don't have children, so to solve that problem i made this else statement:

```
#else
    #set ($str = $nav_item.getURL().substring($nav_item.getURL().lastIndexOf("bc"),$nav_item.getURL().length()))

    #if ($str.equals("bclogin") || $str.equals("bchome") || $str.equals("bcmaintenance"))
        <li>
             <a href="$nav_item.getURL()">
                $nav_item.getName()
             </a>
        </li>
        #end
#end
```

And this solves my whole problem. The only issue about this code is that i need to specify the name of the pages that don't have children witch is not a good principle since that i need to edit this code everytime i add/remove/edit one page.

I'm trying to find better solutions and i'm open to some ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution but it only works if the root pages (in my example are Page 1 and Page 2)  doesn't have any content and they serve only has a child pages agregator. Here is the code:

```
<ul id="mainTopMenu">
    ## First Level Generation

    #set($layoutLocalServiceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService"))

    #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)

        #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())

            <li>
                <a> $nav_item.getName()</a>
                <ul>
                    ## Second Level Generation
                    #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                        <li>            
                            <a href="$nav_child.getURL()">
                                $nav_child.getName()
                            </a>
                        </li>   
                    #end
                </ul>
            </li>

        #else

            #set($lay = $layoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout($nav_item.getLayout().getAncestorPlid()))

            #if (!$lay.hasChildren()) 
                <li>
                    <a href="$nav_item.getURL()">
                        $nav_item.getName()
                    </a>
                </li>
            #end
        #end
    #end
</ul>
```

To make this work we also need to set the Page 1 permissions to 'visible to all logged users' and gave the desired permissions to the child pages.

Answer (score 2):

> I've already removed all the permissions to 'Page 1' expecting that it
>   assumes the children permissions but with this the page is always
>   invisible.

You can think of the relationship between a Page and child-page as a Folder within a sub-folder. So if you remove permission from the Folder, well ... you would not see the folder and hence the sub-folder even if you have permission for the sub-folder.

> What i want is to make 'Page 1' only visible to users who have at
>   least access to one child page.

What i can think of is that, you can have VIEW permissions on `Page 1` as normal and customize your template which renders the page navigation. In that template you can check permissions for each and every child-pages and when even one has permission you can set a flag to show `Page 1` else not.

The only drawback with this is that if the User enters directly the URL for `Page 1` he would be able to see `Page 1` content if there is any. We can stop this as well but I think it would become a little tedious with a Service-pre action or a Filter-hook.

Hope this gives you some idea regarding the approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "The only drawback with this is that if the User enters directly the URL for Page 1 he would be able to see Page 1 content if there is any." This won't be a problem since the Page 1 doesn't have any content. I've edited my answer with some progress i made.